# Bootstrap Modal and select: If user clicks on Cancel, go back to the first item on select

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make the select go back to the first option if the user clicks on Cancel button from Modal box?

Here is my **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/9abm0hhy/96/)** for better clarification.

And this is the script I am using to open modal boxes on select options:

```
$('.selectpicker').change(function() {
    var manage = $(this).val();
    if(manage==="sequenceA"){
        $('.js-my-modal-a').modal("show");
    } else if(manage==="sequenceB") {
        $('.js-my-modal-b').modal("show");
    }
});
```

If the user clicks on Cancel, the select should go back to the `<option data-hidden="true">Manage</option>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9abm0hhy/104/)

```
$('.selectpicker').change(function() {
    var manage = $(this).val();
    if(manage==="sequenceA"){
        $('.js-my-modal-a').modal("show");
    } else if(manage==="sequenceB") {
        $('.js-my-modal-b').modal("show");
    }
});

$(".modal button[data-dismiss='modal']").on("click",function()
                                            {
    $('.selectpicker').attr("title","Manage").find("span.filter-option").text("Manage");
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate! That's exactly what I was looking for!